# Direct proof that nilpotent matrix has zero trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, nilpotence

Does anyone know a proof from the first principles that a nilpotent matrix has zero trace. No eigenvalues, no characteristic polynomials, just definition and basic facts about bases and matrices.

Comment: See also the proof of Theorem 1 in my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2983730/the-characteristic-polynomial-of-a-is-xn-if-and-only-if-texttrai-0/2983792#2983792 .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I assume you want the trace of a matrix $A\in M_n(F)$ to be defined as the sum of the diagonal elements and that you take the coefficients in a (commutative) field $F$. Here is an approach using only basic facts about bases and matrices.

1) Recall <strike>the trace is commutative</strike> $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\mathrm{tr}(BA)$, as shown by the [usual computations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#cite_note-1). In particular the trace is invariant under similarity (change of basis): $\mathrm{tr}(PAP^{-1})=\mathrm{tr} A$ for every $P$ invertible in $M_n(F)$.

2) If $A$ is nilpotent with degree $k$ (i.e. $A^k=0$ but $A^{k-1}\neq 0$), we have the following flag
$$
\{0\}\subseteq \ker A\subseteq \ker A^2\subseteq \ldots\subseteq \ker A^k=F^n
$$
where dimensions are strictly increasing.
Starting with a basis of $\ker A$, we can complete it into a basis of $\ker A^2$ and so on until we get a basis of $F^n$. If $P$ denotes the corresponding change of basis matrix, then $PAP^{-1}$ is strictly upper-triangular as $A(\ker A^j)\subseteq \ker A^{j-1}$. In particular, the diagonal of $PAP^{-1}$ is zero whence $\mathrm{tr}(PAP^{-1})=0$.

Comment: The trace is not commutative. Even in a commutative field.

Comment: @AndréCaldas You are right. It is not commutative, but it is cyclic. I.e., Tr$(ABC)=$Tr$(CAB)$=Tr$(BCA)$, so I believe that is all he needs.

Comment: Nice argument! By the way, the trace is invariant under cyclic permutations. :-)

Comment: @DanielMontealegre: I know. Sorry if I was not of much help... I could have been more didactic.

Comment: I knew this solution, but may be there is something more simple. I doubt whether it exist but anyway let's wait...

Comment: @AndréCaldas Guys, if you managed to find a counter-example to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#cite_note-1), you should publish this without waiting any longer... ;-)

Comment: @Norbert Yes, I assumed you were aware of this argument. But since you did not mention it... it seemed to qualify as basic and elementary.

Comment: @julien: I do not have to prove. You have! Show that $\mathrm{tr}(ABC) = \mathrm{tr}(BAC)$. Cheers.

Comment: @AndréCaldas As much I like jokes, you lost me. Of course $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\mathrm{tr}(BA)$ (the trace is commutative if the ground field is commutative). While the last identity you mentioned is false in general (this permutation is not cyclic). What is this all about?

Comment: @julien André isn't saying that $\mathrm{tr}(AB)\neq\mathrm{tr}(BA)$. But it's misleading to say that the trace is commutative when $\mathrm{tr}(ABC)\neq\mathrm{tr}(BAC)$ in general. It's better to say that it's cyclic.

Comment: @JohnMoeller Ah...thanks for explaining. For (lots of?) people, the trace is commutative simply means $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\mathrm{tr}(BA)$ as it refers to the product as a binary operation.

Comment: @JohnMoeller and julien: I prefer to say that it is invariant under xxxx type of permutations. The trace is not a binary operation, and therefore, I find it misleading to say it is commutative. What is associativity, for example? Now, notice that in case of group operations, for example, commutativity plus associativity gives that $abc = bac$. Is the trace associative? In what sense? But anyway... your solution is very nice!!! Cheers. :-)

Comment: @AndréCaldas Yeah, I agree this is sloppy terminology. It just happens I've heard it many times. But hey, I've edited...;-)

Comment: In step 2) when you say "If P denotes the corresponding change of basis matrix", what change of basis are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working over a field of characteristic $p$, you can view this as a consequence of the identity $Tr(X^p) = Tr(X)^p$, which has a short combinatorial proof by expanding out $Tr(X)^p$. Even though this doesn't apply in generality (i.e. characteristic 0), I still think it is worth mentioning.