# If $A \in M_{2\times 2}(F)$ and $A^{2}=0$ then $tr(A)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

I actually saw an statement here on stackxchange:
"Let $A$ be a square matrix $n \times n$. $trace (A)=0$, if and only if, $A^{2}=0$."

So I could find a counterexample for →.
And I think the statement should be correct only for $2\times 2$ square matrices.

Now I wanna know if we can claim: If $A\in M_{2\times 2}(F)$ and $A^{2}=0$ then $trace(A)=0$.
Am I correct? 
If this makes sense, how do we prove it based on trace and multiplication definitions?

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what your question is. It is true that if $A^2 = 0$, then $\operatorname{trace}(A) = 0$; this holds for matrices of any size. The following is not true for **any** $n \geq 2$: "for a matrix $A$ of size $n$, if $\operatorname{trace}(A) = 0$ then $A^2 = 0$."

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. The statement I saw here, claimed that your later statement was correct.

Comment: So you have any hints about how you prove "if A² = 0 then tr(A) = 0" ? Thanks

Comment: if the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2=0$, the trace (the coefficient on $\lambda$) is $0$

Comment: We can also show that $A^2 = 0$ implies that the trace of $A$ is zero using a [rank-factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization)

Answer (score 2):

$A^2=\pmatrix{a&&b\\c&&d}^2=\pmatrix{a^2+bc&&ab+bd\\ac+dc&&bc+d^2}=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&0}$

$\implies b(a+d)=0$ and $ c(a+d)=0  \implies a+d=0 $ or $b=c=0$,

but if $b=c=0$ then $a^2+bc=0, bc+d^2=0\implies a=d=0\implies a+d=0$ anyways.

So indeed it can be shown based on the definitions of matrix trace and multiplication that

the trace of a $2\times2$ matrix whose square is the $0$ matrix is $0.$

Answer (score 2):

In general, the statement "if $A^2 = 0$, then $\operatorname{tr}(A) = 0$" can be proven using the fact that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues. One proof for the specific case of $2 \times 2$ matrices is as follows.

It's clear that if $A = 0$, then $A^2 = 0$ and $\operatorname{trace}(A) = 0$. So, suppose that $A^2 = 0$ but $A \neq 0$. Because $A^2 = 0$, $A$ cannot be an invertible matrix. It follows that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent. As a consequence, we can write $A$ in the form $A = xy^T$ for some vectors $x$ and $y$ (in particular, we can let $x$ be a non-zero column of $A$).

Verify that the trace of $A$ is also equal to $y^Tx$. On the other hand, note that 
$$
A^2 = (xy^T)(xy^T) = x(y^Tx)y^T = (y^Tx) \cdot xy^T = \operatorname{trace}(A) \cdot A.
$$ 
So, $A^2 = 0$ implies that $\operatorname{trace}(A) = 0$.

Comment: Question:  Say $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with $n\ge3$ and $A^2=0$ and $A\ne0$.  The Cayley-Hamilton theorem then says $x^2$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $A$, right?  How does that prove tr$(A)=0$?

Comment: @J now that I think about it I guess the Cayley Hamilton theorem isn’t much help. The fact that $A^2=0$ tells us that zero is the only eigenvalue of $A$, which means that the sum of the eigenvalues is zero

Comment: Thank you for the explanation; $+1$; I found a related answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2078749)

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is right but the following is not true for any $n≥2$ : "for a matrix A of size $n$, if $trace(A)=0$ then $A^2=0$.

If $A=0$ then it is easy to see that $trace(A)=0$

Suppose $A\ne 0$ but $A^2=0$ , then $\exists x\in F^2$ such that $Ax\ne 0$

You see $\{x,Ax\}$ forms a basis of $F^2$.(why?)

> Let $c_1x+c_2Ax=0$ where $c_1,c_2\in F$ . Then $A(c_1x+c_2Ax)=0\implies c_1Ax+c_2A^2x=0$ .
>    Then $c_1=0$ and $c_2=0$.

So ${x,Ax}$ linearly independent hence the basis of $F^2$.

Look at the matrix of $A$ with respect to this matrix it is
$\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\1&0
\end {pmatrix}$ as $A(x)=0\cdot x +1\cdot Ax$ and $A(Ax)=A^2x=0\cdot x +0\cdot Ax.$

So the $trace(A)=0$.